# ggplot2 - Add two legends (geom_point and color_gradient)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to have two different legends in my ggplot graphic.
One for the color gradient and another one to explain the red marked dots.

The legend for the red circles should contain only one line and an individual text.

I am only able to create the color gradient scale, but not the other one:

```
data <- data.frame(A = runif(10, 0, 10), 
                   B = runif(10, 0, 10), 
                   color = runif(10, 0, 10), 
                   density = runif(10, 0, 10), 
                   red = rep(1:5, each=2))

ggplot(data, aes(A, B, color = color, alpha = 1/density)) +
  geom_point(shape = 16, size = 5, show.legend = T) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12, family = 'serif'),
        axis.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold", family = 'serif'),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "white", high = "black", name = "Scale", breaks = c(8,2), labels = c("max","min"))+
  geom_point(data = data[data$red == 1,],color="red",size=5, alpha = 0.7, show.legend = T) +
  scale_alpha(range = c(.5, .7), breaks = data$A[1], labels = c("1")) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log10', name = "A") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log10', name = "B")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have to assign the `aes()` for the `scale_alpha()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(A = runif(10, 0, 10), 
                   B = runif(10, 0, 10), 
                   color = runif(10, 0, 10), 
                   density = runif(10, 0, 10), 
                   red = rep(1:5, each=2))

ggplot(data, aes(A, B, color = color, alpha = 1/density)) +
  geom_point(shape = 16, size = 5, show.legend = T) +
  geom_point(data = data[data$red == 1,],color="red",size=5, alpha = 0.7, show.legend = T) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12, family = 'serif'),
        axis.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold", family = 'serif'),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "white", high = "black", name = "Scale", breaks = c(8,2), labels = c("max","min"))+
  scale_alpha(range = c(.5, .7), aes(breaks = data$A[1], labels = c("1"))) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log10', name = "A") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log10', name = "B")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That works great. Could you tell me how to show only one red circle in the legend with an individual text?

Comment: What do you mean, limit the data shown in the legend?

Comment: Exactly. Just one red circle and one word.